# issue: when an image is displayed on this camera and contains a glow effect, it becomes black

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

Solved. Please see my answer below.

```
---------------------------
```

Edit 3:

It's almost solved. Last push please.
I tried the scale and the modulateGlow that Rabbid76 suggested and the butterflies are transparent. Please look at the butterfly on the chair and the big one on the floor.

[image]

And here are the original images(one of them) :

[image]
---------------------------

Edit 2:

Thanks to Rabbid76, it's almost solved!
The left image shows the current result with Rabbid76 solution. The right image shows the expected solution. As you see, the butterflies became lighter\transparent now.

[image]

```
---------------------------
```

Edit 1:

I tried to add the suggested glBlendFunc and it didn't help although it affected the glow effect a little bit. I needed to add GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND) because it's disabled by default.

```
---------------------------
```

I'm using this repository

https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android

It contains filters that can be displayed on the camera. One of the filters is named "WATERMARK". When I change this image to be an image with a glow effect, the glow becomes black.

The image is located at: GPUVideo-android-master\sample\src\main\res\drawable-nodpi\sample_bitmap.png. In order to trigger the problem, it should be changed to an image with glow effect. For example I generated this image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u8PtIftovPbXRLnI3OR9_1Kv37L5s96_/view?usp=sharing

You can see the issue with the white glow effect that becomes black:
[image: the white glow effect becomes light black]

Just run the app, click on "Camera Record", then choose "Portrait" and from the left list choose "WATERMARK" (the 5th from the end). Don't forget to change the image I mentioned.

The relevant class is named: GlWatermarkFilter. It extends GlOverlayFilter which contains the next shader:

```
 private final static String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "uniform lowp sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
                "uniform lowp sampler2D oTexture;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "   lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                "   lowp vec4 textureColor2 = texture2D(oTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                "   \n" +
                "   gl_FragColor = mix(textureColor, textureColor2, textureColor2.a);\n" +
                "}\n";
```

and this class also contains this setup:

```
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

This class extends GlFilter which contains:

```
protected static final String DEFAULT_VERTEX_SHADER =
        "attribute highp vec4 aPosition;\n" +
                "attribute highp vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
                "varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "gl_Position = aPosition;\n" +
                "vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord.xy;\n" +
                "}\n";

protected static final String DEFAULT_FRAGMENT_SHADER =
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
                "varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "uniform lowp sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                "}\n";
```

Please help me to figure out how to fix it. I know it's something about semi-alpha issue and this camera that doesn't know to display it. My goal is to record a video with glowing butterflies.

Comment: I would guess it's something to do with blend mode. Search for `glBlendFunc` and maybe try additive `GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE);` or premultiplied `GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Comment: Thanks. I tried to add: GLES20.glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) and with the options you mentioned but I didn't notice any change.

Comment: I added GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND) because it's disabled by default but not working yet. It really changes the glow effect color so sometimes it's darker and sometimes it looks the same more or less.

Comment: Most likely, the color channel of the glow effect texture fades out at the edges of the glowing area. This means that the texture's color channels at the edges of the glowing area have a gradient from white to black. If this is the case you wrongly `mix` the textures. You need to add the glow effect (`textureColor2`) to the base texture (`textureColor`): `gl_FragColor = textureColor + textureColor2;`. Note that this is just a guess as I can't see the glow effect texture.

Comment: Another option would be `gl_FragColor = textureColor + textureColor2 * textureColor2.a;`

Comment: wow it is so closed to the solution! it really removed the black color. Now the problem is that the butterflies are too light. They look light pink, almost transparent. Have an idea how to fix it? I'll edit the post in a few minutes. (tried both of your suggestions)

Comment: *"Now the problem is that the butterflies are too light."* - I don't think they are too ligth. This is the desired glow effect created by the effects shader. You can try to scale down the glow texture: `gl_FragColor = textureColor + textureColor2 * 0.5;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves all the issues so please notice the last 2 lines:

```
private final static String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "uniform lowp sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
                "uniform lowp sampler2D oTexture;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "   lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                "   lowp vec4 textureColor2 = texture2D(oTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                "   lowp float alphaDivisor = textureColor2.a + step(textureColor2.a, 0.0);\n" +
                "   gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(textureColor.rgb, textureColor2.rgb / alphaDivisor, textureColor2.a), textureColor.a);\n" +
                "}\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the color channel of the glow effect texture fades out at the edges of the glowing area. This means that the texture's color channels at the edges of the glowing area have a gradient from white to black. If this is the case you wrongly mix the textures. You need to add the glow effect (textureColor2) to the base texture (`textureColor`):

```c
gl_FragColor = textureColor + textureColor2;
```

An option would be scale the glow effect texture by it's alpha channel

```c
gl_FragColor = textureColor + textureColor2 * textureColor2.a;
```

If the glow effect seems too bright, you can reduce the glow effect by scaling the glow texture:

```c
float scale = 0.5;
gl_FragColor = textureColor + textureColor2 * scale;
```

Or you can modulate the glow effect through the color texture:

```c
vec4 modulateGlow = textureColor2 * textureColor;
gl_FragColor = textureColor + modulateGlow;
```

Comment: Please see my Edit 3. I attached another 2 images there. 
The result now is not as the butterflies really look in the png. Maybe the FRAGMENT_SHADER  or the DEFAULT_VERTEX_SHADER should be changed more?